# Error FormatException received when api callled on localhost "127.0.0.1/app/sanjhapizza/lib/userLogin.php" in flutter

Tags: flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

**this is my code which contains API call code.The following error rceived while executing this code:
Exception:FormatException: //127.0.0.1/app/sanjhapizza/lib/userLogin
Api result:failed
Error: Assertion failed:

Please help me

```
import 'dart:convert';
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
Future<String> userLogin(String userid) async {
try {
String ulink = "http://127.0.0.1/app/sanjhapizza/lib/userLogin.php";
final response = await http.post(Uri.http(ulink),
body: {"userid": userid});
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
} on Exception catch (e) {
print("Exception:$e");
return ("failed");
}
}
```